# Firewall settings for Dropbox LAN sync

Tags: sync, firewall, dropbox, lan

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 computers on a wireless home network, kept in sync using Dropbox. I use Dropbox rather than Ubuntu One because of its LAN sync feature - preferable to doing everything via the internet.

Will using GUFW (firewall) disable this LAN sync function? If so, how do I get round it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a firewall will disable LAN sync. You must configure it to allow connections to port 17500 to make it work.

More info about LAN sync [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/137/en).